# NServiceBus Handlers' chain of execution graceful break

Tags: nservicebus

There is the option in the NServiceBus to manage the order of handler's execution.

For example, we have:

- AuthorizationHandler : IHandleMessages< Message1 >(for security verification)
- WorkHandler : Saga < Data >, IAmStartedByMessages< Message1 > (actual BL)

We can define order by writing:

```
public void SpecifyOrder(Order order)
{
   order.Specify(First<AuthorizationHandler>.Then<WorkHandler());
}
```

Question is:

If I want to stop message handling in the case that the AuthorizationHandler decides, so it won't be handled by next handler, how can I do it nicely? Without throwing exceptions etc...?

Thank you in advance

Yevgeny

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy: `bus.DoNotContinueDispatchingCurrentMessageToHandlers()` if I recall correctly